# Where my pdf file save in iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

I have use this code for download pdf in iPhone on button click are as:-

```
- (IBAction)download:(id)sender {

    self.downloadedMutableData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.tutorialspoint.com//objective_c/objective_c_tutorial.pdf"]
                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:60.0];
    self.connectionManager = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
}


#pragma mark - Delegate Methods
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"%lld", response.expectedContentLength);
    self.urlResponse = response;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.downloadedMutableData appendData:data];
    progress.progress = ((100.0/self.urlResponse.expectedContentLength)*self.downloadedMutableData.length)/100;
    if (progress.progress == 1) {
        progress.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        progress.hidden = NO;
    }
    float percentage=((100.0/self.urlResponse.expectedContentLength)*self.downloadedMutableData.length);
    percentageLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%",percentage];
    NSLog(@"%.0f%%",percentage);
}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSLog(@"Finished");
    if (self.downloadedMutableData)
            {
                NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"Pdf.pdf"];
                [self.downloadedMutableData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            }
}
```

I don't know where my pdf file is save in iPhone. I want to save pdf file in Gallery in iPhone.
Can you help me?

Comment: You can't. PDF files are not image files, so you cannot save them with other images/photos. Your file has been saved in your apps sandbox, and by default is not accessible by other apps. You should read this, if you haven't already : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: your file is saving here in your code  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath], @"Pdf.pdf"];

Comment: I have print the filePath then   the output is :-  /var/containers/Bundle/Application/6178EA14-8051-49BA-88F8-68444002AB52/DownloadPdfFromLinkDemo.app/Pdf.pdf
But i don't know how can i go this path in iphone.